# Get XML child nodes and concatanate values with ; in Groovy

Tags: string, list, groovy

I have bellow XML document:
xmlIn:

```
<SalesOrder>
<Parameter>Parameter1</Parametro>
<Method>Method1</Metodo>
<Orders>
<Order>
    <Salesman>44</Salesman>
    <Customer>12345</Customer>
    <OrderNumber>100200300</OrderNumber>
</Order>
<Order>
    <Salesman>45</Salesman>
    <Customer>67890</Customer>
    <OrderNumber>400500600</OrderNumber>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

And I have a request to transform into a string in Groovy:

Field1;Field2;Field3

44;12345;100200300

45;67890;400500600

My source code is:

```
def parser = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlIn)
        String header = 'Field1;Field2;Field3'
        def lines = parser.Orders.Order.children().each { 
            it.text()
        }.join(";")
        prinln(header + "\n" + lines)
```

However this is producing:

Field1;Field2;Field3

44;12345;100200300;45;67890;400500600

Does anyone can help me on this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
def lines = parser.Orders.Order.collect{order->
    order.children().collect{it.text()}.join(';')
}.join('\n')
```